# Upgrading qgis in debian jessie (linux)?

Tags: qgis, installation, debian

I want to upgrade qgis 2.6 to qgis 2.8 in linux (debian jessie). I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

And I get this error:

Até aqui tudo bem...

```
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libqgis_core.so.2.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up qgis-common (1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up osgearth-data (2.5.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up qgis-plugin-globe-common (1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-globe:
 qgis-plugin-globe depends on qgis (= 1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

I found the solution. The error was in qgis providers. So I uninstall qgis providers (`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qgis-providers`) and I install qgis without problems.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with dependencies. Have you tried to uninstall and then install qgis again? Try: `apt-get purge qgis` first to uninstall package qgis with all dependencies.

Comment: [deb http//qgis.org/debian jessie main] Jessie (8.x; testing, not yet released): http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I try apt-get purge qgis and I get an error:

Setting up qgis-providers (1:2.9.0+git20150224+4629205+13jessie) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libqgis_core.so.2.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I don't know if the uninstall is done correctly.